# Adding legend to layerd chart in altair

Tags: python, legend, altair

Consider the following example:

```py
    import altair as alt
    from vega_datasets import data

    df = data.seattle_weather()

    temp_max = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(color='blue').encode(
        x='yearmonth(date):T',
        y='max(temp_max)',
    )

    temp_min = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(color='red').encode(
        x='yearmonth(date):T',
        y='max(temp_min)',
    )

    temp_max + temp_min
```

In the resulting chart, I would like to add a legend that shows, that the blue line shows the maximum temperature and the red line the minimum temperature. What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

I saw (e.g. in the solution to this question: [Labelling Layered Charts in Altair (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921991/labelling-layered-charts-in-altair-python)) that altair only adds a legend if in the encoding, you set the *color* or *size* or so, usually with a categorical column, but that is not possible here because I'm plotting the whole column and the label should be the column name (which is now shown in the y-axis label).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do a [fold transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/fold.html#user-guide-fold-transform) such that the variables could be encoded correctly.

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

df = data.seattle_weather()

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().transform_fold(
    fold=['temp_max', 'temp_min'], 
    as_=['variable', 'value']
).encode(
    x='yearmonth(date):T',
    y='max(value):Q',
    color='variable:N'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do this with layered charts? The suggested approach works when the data is in the same dataframe but that is not always the case.

Comment: @Karim there is no way to add a legend without specifying an encoding that the legend will represent. The issue is discussed further here https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/984

Answer (score 0):

If you layer two charts with the same columns and tell them to color by the same one, the legend will appear. Don't know is this helps but..

For example, i had:

---

Range, Amount, Type

0_5,   3,      'Private'

5_10,  5,      'Private'

---

Range, Amount, Type

0_5,   3,      'Public'

5_10,  5,      'Public'

---

and I charted both with 'color = 'Type'' and said alt.layer(chart1, chart2) and it showed me a proper legend