# How to add legend to python altair

Tags: python, charts, legend, altair

Can someone please help how to add legend for "Covid-19 Cases" and "Sales Volume" ?
In the chart, red is "COVID-19 Cases" and blue is the "Sales Volume". Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
# Create the chart
chart1 = alt.Chart(df_county).mark_line(color='red').encode(
    x=alt.X('Date', title='Date'),
    y=alt.Y('Cases', title='COVID-19 Cases'))


chart2 = alt.Chart(df_county).mark_line(color='blue').encode(
    x=alt.X('Date', title='Date'),
    y=alt.Y('Sale Volume', title='Sale Volume'))

chart = chart1 + chart2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to add a legend without specifying an encoding that the legend will represent. The issue is discussed further here https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/984

See
[Adding legend to layerd chart in altair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60128774/adding-legend-to-layerd-chart-in-altair/60128871#60128871) for a similar question.

You can either use a [Fold Transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/fold.html?highlight=fold) if both values have the same units, or you could introduce a [Dual Y Axis](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/scale_resolve.html?highlight=dual%20axis#dual-y-axis) without a legend.