# Altair: Layered Line Chart with Legend and Custom Colors

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair, vega-lite

I'm creating a layered line chart with 2 lines in Altair, each with a custom color. I want to add a legend to this. My original code, without the legend, looks like this:

```
source = df

line1 = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x='Date:T', 
    y='FeatureOne:Q', 
    color= alt.value('gold')
)

line2 = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x='Date:T', 
    y=alt.Y('FeatureTwo:Q', title='Value'), 
    color= alt.value('red')
)

line1 + line2
```

Here's the viz:

[image]

I wanted to add a legend to this and thankfully, there was a [good answer on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60128774/adding-legend-to-layerd-chart-in-altair) previously.

However, what I can't figure out is how to use the legend, while also keeping the custom color. I can only do one or the other. Is there a way to do both? For instance, if I follow the code in the answer linked above, my code looks like this:

```
source = df

line1 = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().transform_fold(
    fold=['FeatureOne'], 
    as_=['variable', 'value']
).encode(
    x='Date:T', 
    y='FeatureOne:Q', 
#     color= alt.value('gold')
    color='variable:N'
)

line2 = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().transform_fold(
    fold=['FeatureTwo'], 
    as_=['variable', 'value']
).encode(
    x='Date:T', 
    y=alt.Y('FeatureTwo:Q', title='Value'), 
#     color= alt.value('red')
    color='variable:N'
)

line1 + line2
```

That gives me a layered line chart with a legend, but I can't set the color of the lines. So it looks a bit like this:

[image]

How would I change this, so that I get my custom line colors in my 1st example:

```
color= alt.value('red')
```

While also doing the legend:

```
color='variable:N'
```

Is there a good way to do both at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a custom color scale like this:

```python
scale = alt.Scale(domain=['FeatureOne', 'FeatureTwo'], range=['gold', 'red'])
```

Then pass this scale to one or both of the color encodings in your chart:

```python
color=alt.Color('variable:N', scale=scale)
```

But note that if you're already using a fold transform, there's no reason to do the layering manually; this should work to draw both lines at once:

```python
alt.Chart(source).mark_line().transform_fold(
    fold=['FeatureOne', 'FeatureTwo'], 
    as_=['variable', 'value']
).encode(
    x='Date:T', 
    y='value:Q',
    color=alt.Color('variable:N', scale=scale)
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Jake! That works perfectly.