# Layering charts removes marks from one chart

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I have the following data:

- Various measurements (each with a name) over a time-interval which I want to plot (one line each)
- One measurement is called 'State' which I want to use to color the background of the chart (vertical slices)

The measurement dataframe looks approx like this:

```
                     Time Trend  Value
0     2021-03-24 16:10:20     A   -1.3
1     2021-03-24 16:10:35     A   -5.3
2     2021-03-24 16:10:50     A   -6.3
3     2021-03-24 16:11:05     A   -2.3
4     2021-03-24 22:39:05     A   -5.3
...                   ...   ...    ...
12443 2021-03-24 16:10:20     H    0.0
12444 2021-03-24 22:38:20     H    1.0
12445 2021-03-24 22:38:35     H    2.0
12446 2021-03-24 22:38:50     H    3.0
12447 2021-03-24 22:39:05     H    4.0
```

For this purpose, I extract the time-ranges where a certain state is "active", as here:

```
      State               Start                 End
0      Idle 2021-03-24 16:10:20 2021-03-24 16:10:50
1      Pump 2021-03-24 16:10:50 2021-03-24 16:20:05
...
5      Cool 2021-03-24 20:42:20 2021-03-24 22:01:35
6      Pump 2021-03-24 22:01:35 2021-03-24 22:02:50
```

I then create two charts which I would like to combine with alt.layer

- One with lines for each Measurement (Trend)
- One with rectangles for each State

```
 alt_st = (
        alt.Chart(state_df)
        .mark_rect()
        .encode(
            x=alt.X("Start", title="Time"),
            x2=alt.X2("End", title="Time"),
            y=alt.value(15),
            y2=alt.value(0),
            color=alt.Color("State:O", scale=get_state_scale(state_df.State.unique())),
        )
        # .add_selection(selection)
    )
```

[image: rectangle state chart]

```
chart = (
    alt.Chart(df)
    .mark_line()
    .encode(
        alt.X("Time"),
        alt.Y("Value"),
        color="Trend",
    )
)
```

[image: measurement chart]

Combining with `alt.layer`:

```
alt.layer(chart, alt_st).resolve_legend("independent")
```

[image: Combined chart]

As can be seen, the combined chart has a messed up legend and the marks (lines) from the first chart) are gone.

What I tried so far:

- Looking at Issues in the GitHub repo of altair and Vega-Lite
- Changing the order (doesn't help)
- Using vConcat instead (doesn't help)
- Removing the custom scale from the state-chart (this helped but the result wasn't pretty either)

The last thing I found out when trying to create a minimal example here.

[image: without scale]

I found a similar question ([Altair: Layered Line Chart with Legend and Custom Colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65226756/altair-layered-line-chart-with-legend-and-custom-colors)) but couldn't work out how to apply the solution for my case.

My impression so far is that what I'm doing is very unidiomatic for Altair/Vega-Lite - if someone could point out the relevant concepts I'm missing I would be glad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have at the end looks correct, but you would want to use `resolve_scale(color='independent')` instead of `resolve_legend('independent')` to separate the legends correctly:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.iowa_electricity()
# Create end year for mark_rect
source['end_year'] = source.groupby('source')['year'].shift(-1)
source = source.dropna()

line = alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x="year:T",
    y="net_generation:Q",
    color="source:N")

bar = alt.Chart(source).mark_rect().encode(
    x="year:T",
    x2="end_year",
    color='year(year):O',
    y=alt.value(15),
    y2=alt.value(0)
)

(bar + line).resolve_scale(color='independent')
```

[image]

You can move the bar to the bottom with `mark_rect(yOffset=270, y2Offset=300)` (offsets are in pixels rather than chart units, the same as when you use alt.value for y and y2):

[image]